# Deleting a function defined in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm starting to learn haskell and find myself having to restart the repl again and again because I defined incorrect specialization for a function and I don't know how to delete them.

For example, let's say I made the error of putting the base case of `n == 0` after the general case for a factorial function:

```
fact n = n * fact(n-1)
fact 0 = 1
```

This is obviously wrong, now if I repeat the general case, it will be added to the current list, giving me 3 overloads for `fact`.

How do I delete the first case that I defined, or all the definitions of `fact` if possible. Is it possible to delete a function I defined in GHCI? If yes, how?

Comment: Doesn't redefining it work?

Comment: Just define one again.

Comment: @n.m. I've edited the post to include an example.

Comment: AFAICT that's not how GHCi works. These are not "overloads" or "specialisations". These are *complete* definitions, all three of them. You need to use either multiline definitions (:set +m) or braces to actually define a working factorial function.

Comment: Please don't be down-to-earth and look at what the op is actually asking. He's not asking "how to solve his code", he knows the code is wrong because it's an example of wrong code (on purpose). Instead he's asking how to remove a variable that has been defined.

Answer (score 7):

```
Prelude> fact n = n * fact (n-1)
Prelude> fact 0 = 1
Prelude> fact 3
*** Exception: <interactive>:6:1-10: Non-exhaustive patterns in function fact
Prelude> :q
Leaving GHCi.
bash> ghci
Prelude> fact 0 = 1
Prelude> fact n = n * fact (n-1)
Prelude> fact 3
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

What's going on?

With GHC, the *first* definition would result in a stack overflow, and the second one would be correct.

But in GHCi each binding *shadows* the previous one with the same name. In the example above, in each of the sessions each line that contains an equation for `fact` is a complete definition. When `fact 3` is called, only the second line is in effect, and the first one is invisible.

So you cannot define functions the same way you do in normal GHC.

To define the factorial function correctly you can use one of these three methods.

1. A braced definition with no layout.

   ```
   Prelude> let { fact 0 = 1; fact n = n * fact(n-1) }
   ```
2. A multiline definition with special GHCi braces.

   ```
   Prelude> :{
   Prelude| let fact 0 = 1
   Prelude|     fact n = n * fact (n-1)
   Prelude| :}
   ```
3. A multiline definition with no special braces (needs `:set +m` which can be added to your `~/.ghci`)

   ```
   Prelude> let fact 0 = 1 
   Ptelude|     fact n = n * fact (n-1)
   Prelude|
   Prelude>
   ```

See the [manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#interactive-evaluation-at-the-prompt) for more imformation.

Note I have used `let` in these definitions, because I'm used to them, but they are in fact not necessary in newer versions of GHCi.

Comment: Or you can just surround a multiline definition by `:{` `:}` on their own lines

Comment: @bradrn yes, just added this

Comment: In modern GHCi one can also omit the `let`, as the OP did (I think).

Comment: @chi thanks, I didn't know that! Added to the answer.

Comment: with proper multiline entry, each new definition indeed overrides the previous one. what *does* happen though, is when we define *instances*, I think each new definition is added to a list, not overrides them. maybe that's what the OP meant.

Comment: @WillNess, to fix an instance definition you can either define the type again or define the class again. But by that point, you should probably have just opened up a `.hs` file.

Comment: it kills me that people post answers without understanding the question. The question is not "how to solve this example of invalid code" but "how to delete a function that has been already defined".

Comment: @Eric OP had a problem and didn't know what question to ask. I have tried to solve OP's problem, not to answer the question as asked. You are welcome to add your own answer if you think it would be useful.

Comment: I came here because I had the same problem, so it's a genuine problem. Interpreting and answering another question may help indeed but it may also confuse and in the end be a waste of time.

Comment: @Eric I did my best to help OP solve their problem. Did my answer help *you* solve *your* problem? If not, you can ask a question and provide a link to this one and explain why this answer was a waste of time for *you*.